# Issue with react version and cant find way to downgrade version

Tags: reactjs, error-handling, react-navigation, yarnpkg

I wanted to add navigation with react router but got errors countless number of times. Tried no. Of things. Upgraded version from yarn package. Then its saying to downgrade version to version 0.66 to 0.64. But don't know how to downgrade version of react.

Answer (score 0):

Just run `npm install <package>@<version>`

or

change package version in `package.json` from `"react-native": "0.66.2"` to `"react-native": "0.64.2"` and run `npm install` or `yarn install`